# Spring mvc multiple entities database persistance

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm having troubles with "working with multiple databases" in Spring MVC - hibernate JPA

I have two databases called *user_db* and *portal_db*. I need to work with them in different jpa units.

here is my **persistance.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="user_unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>Package.Entity1</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/user_db" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect" />
            <!--<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />-->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="portal_unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>Package.Entity2</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/portal_db" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect" />
            <!--<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>-->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Problem is When I use create-drop and run my project, it creates both of my entites in both databases. Like table that should be only created by `Package.Entity1` in user_unit, is also created in portal_unit.

And when I select,insert,update my entites, I set persistance unit in each of my individual DAO's.

for example, in Entity Dao's implementation I have:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnit);
```

where **persistenceUnit** could be `user_unit` or `portal_unit` depending on implementation.

What changes should I make so it wont create same table in both databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>` in both of yours persistence units OR use JPA 2.x

Comment: It worked. thanks :) I mark is as correct answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Add `<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>` in both your persistence units.

Please follow post below for detailed explanation:

[Multiple persistance unit in persistence.xml creating tables in one another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853994/multiple-persistance-unit-in-persistence-xml-creating-tables-in-one-another)

Comment: Thanks for the details :)