# Multiple DB configuration in java spring throws exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I am using two different databases for my spring hibernate application.

I defined two persistence config file for creating two session factory.
When i start the servlet container it throws below exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource
```

PersistenceConfig1

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "com.test.test2.*" })
public class PersistenceConfiguration1 {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name="fSessionFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(testDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {
                " com.test.test2"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties1());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource testDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(
            SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties hibernateProperties1() {
        return new Properties() {
            {
                setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                        env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
                setProperty("hibernate.dialect",
                        env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
                setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Persistence Config 2

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "com.test.test3.*" })
public class PersistenceConfigurationDOTC {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name="dSessionFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(test1DataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {
                "com.test.test3.entity"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource test1DataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc1.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc1.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc1.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc1.pass"));

        return dataSource;
    }


    Properties hibernateProperties() {
        return new Properties() {
            {
                setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                        env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
                setProperty("hibernate.dialect",
                        env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
                setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

If I defined two transaction manager also im getting exception.
Help me on how to configure two transaction managers in one spring hibernate application.

Comment: Please see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37248159/spring-mvc-multiple-entities-database-persistance/37248318?noredirect=1#comment62027042_37248318

Comment: @shankarsh15 I am defining all the sessionfactory / data source in java instead of XML

Comment: have a look at this post as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308035/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-with-multiple-datasources

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a single transaction manager for both the configs? Or would you prefer a multiple config? Try defining transaction manager in your Persistence Config 2 too.

Comment: If i defined two transaction i am getting below exception                                 No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2 session factory